# Getting nicer values for eigensystems

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I want to find the eigensystem of the matrix `{{0.9, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}}`. I tried

```
Eigensystem[{{0.9, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}}]
```

The result is horrifying

> ```
> {{1., 0.4}, {{0.980581, 0.196116}, {-0.707107, 0.707107}}}
> ```

What do I mean by that? Well, the first eigenvector could be written as `{5, 1}`, and the second can be written as `{-1, 1}`. I'm assuming it choose the first solution for each, based on the numbers in our matrix.

How could I automate the process though? How can I make sure that it yields the cleaner answer that I wrote above? (Maybe force integers somehow? But this won't always be the case for the simplest answer)

Comment: Try `Eigensystem[Rationalize@{{0.9, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}}]` and read the documentation carefully.  This is all explained there.

Comment: Mathematica returns normalized eigenvectors for numerical inputs.

Comment: Ah, thank you both, now I know why. And also how to get nicer answer from Mathematica :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be happier with this?

```
Eigensystem[{{0.9, 0.5}, {0.1, 0.5}} // Rationalize]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2/5}, {{5, 1}, {-1, 1}}}
> ```